# What component has the reference designator RY?

Tags: pcb, components, fuses, code, varistor

I found a component designated RY8015 which I don't recognize, shown on the photo below on an LCD TV PCB (the bulb-like part next to a green radial varistor).

What is it called? What is its design function?

[image: image of the PCB with the part in question]

Comment: Looks like a regular neon bulb, probably for overvoltage protection.

Comment: It's a neon; they're used for a few different things. Usually it's some form of voltage control, either clipping overvoltage, or triggering & discharging in an RC sawtooth oscillator circuit.

Answer (score 4):

It is a discharge tube, possibly neon filled.... Normally it remains as open circuit, but if some part of the circuit received or generated higher than nominal voltage, the discharge tube fires and the resultant current will serve as the input for the detection circuit so that the abnormal condition can corrected.